# What is the meaning of 'NK' in pandas int64?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I have a column *pathsize* (int64). However, I got some values define as 'NK'. I've tried to convert this value into an integer, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
NK    687
15    180
12    172
14    166
...
3     123
Name: pathsize, Length: 92, dtype: int64
```

The script I used to convert NK into 0:

```
def pathsize(row):
    if (row["pathsize"] != 'NK'):
        return row["pathsize"]
    return 0

df['pathsize'] = df.apply(pathsize, axis=1)
```

The script works fine, but when I try to process the data (convert it as a float), I got this following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' NK'
```

Comment: where does your input data come from ?

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo, my input data comes from a *.csv* file. I'm imported the data using `pandas.read_csv` method.

Comment: I think NK here is value of an index rather than value in column that is why converting it to integer has no effect. What you need to do is to use string replace to replace NK with some value and then convert it to integer of float.

Comment: @SaberAlex can you update your question with a sample of the csv file, including the row which is presented as 'NK' after you read it with python. Further more, please update your question with the code which actuallly reads this file.